# Is $f(s) = \int\limits_a^b k(s,t) \: g(t) \:dt$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $k: [a,b] \times [a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Let $$M=\sup\{|k(s,t) : (s,t) \in [a,b] \times [a,b]\}$$
For $g \in C[a,b],$ is the following function continuous?

$$f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}, \quad f(s) = \int\limits_a^b k(s,t) \: g(t) \:dt$$

I don't have any idea how can I solve this question. I need some help.

Comment: You can use \mathbb{C}, for example.

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: You define M, but say nothing about it nor use it anywhere.

Comment: @ir7 I know but this is how it is written in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $g$ is not null, hence $\int\limits_a^b|g(t)| dt > 0 $ (we use $g$'s continuity here).

Let $\epsilon >0$.

As $k$ is continuous on a compact interval, it is uniformly continous, so there is $\delta >0$ such that
$$ |k(x,t) - k(y,t)|<\frac{\epsilon}{\int\limits_a^b|g(t)|dt} =:\epsilon^\star $$
for all $x,y\in [a,b]$ such that $|x-y| <\delta$ and all $t\in [a,b]$.

We then have:

$$ |f(x) - f(y)| = |\int\limits_a^b k(x,t) \: g(t) \:dt - \int\limits_a^b k(y,t) \: g(t) \:dt | $$ $$ \leq \int\limits_a^b |k(x,t) - k(y,t)| \: |g(t)| \:dt 
< \epsilon^\star \int\limits_a^b|g(t)| dt= \epsilon$$

for all $x,y\in [a,b]$ such that $|x-y| <\delta$, proving the uniform continuity of $f$.